# How can I display all of the elements stored in the array?

Tags: c

How can I display all of the elements stored in the array? I just only want to display all the inputted elements.

This is my code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  #include<conio.h>
  #include<string.h>

  struct studinfo{
    char remarks, name[100];
    float first, second, finalave;
};

int main()
{
    struct studinfo stud;
    int i, n;
    char temp;
    
    printf("Enter Number of Student/s to be Stored: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Student Name: ");
        scanf("%c", &temp);
        scanf("%[^\n]", stud.name);
        printf("Enter 1st Sem Average: ");
        scanf("%f", &stud.first);
        printf("Enter 2nd Sem Average: ");
        scanf("%f", &stud.second);
        stud.finalave = (stud.first + stud.second) /2 ;
        printf("\nThe Final Average: %f", stud.finalave);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (stud.finalave > 1.0 && stud.finalave <= 1.25 )
        {
            stud.remarks = 'S';
        }
        else if (stud.finalave > 1.5 && stud.finalave <= 1.75)
        {
            stud.remarks = 'A';
        }
        else if (stud.finalave > 2.0 && stud.finalave <= 2.5)
        {
            stud.remarks = 'B';
        }
        else if (stud.finalave > 2.75 && stud.finalave <= 3.0)
        {
            stud.remarks = 'C';
        }
        else if (stud.finalave >= 3.00)
        {
            stud.remarks = 'F';
        }
    }
```

This is where the error in displaying:

```
    printf("\n");
    printf("Name\t\tAverage\t\tRemarks\t\tScholarship");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    printf("\n%s\t%f\t%c", stud.name, stud.finalave, stud.remarks);
    }
}
```

My expected output for this code is that all the inputted elements will be displayed     but it turns out that only the last inputted are detected. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: To clarify some confusion, what do you think where the second set of infos is stored? Or where to you think that the first set survives, once you start entering the second?

Answer (score 0):

First, define an array of structures like `struct studinfo stud[n]` in replace of 'n' you can use any variable. Then when taking the input use `stud[i].name` here `i` represents the index of the array.
And for displaying you can use `stud[i].name` similar to getting input.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<string.h>
  struct studinfo{
    char remarks, name[100];
    float first, second, finalave;
};

int main()
{
    
    int i, n;
    char temp;
    
    printf("Enter Number of Student/s to be Stored: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct studinfo stud[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Student Name: ");
        scanf("%c", &temp);
        scanf("%[^\n]", stud[i].name);
        printf("Enter 1st Sem Average: ");
        scanf("%f", &stud[i].first);
        printf("Enter 2nd Sem Average: ");
        scanf("%f", &stud[i].second);
        stud[i].finalave = (stud[i].first + stud[i].second) /2 ;
        printf("\nThe Final Average: %f", stud[i].finalave);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (stud[i].finalave > 1.0 && stud[i].finalave <= 1.25 )
        {
            stud[i].remarks = 'S';
        }
        else if (stud[i].finalave > 1.5 && stud[i].finalave <= 1.75)
        {
            stud[i].remarks = 'A';
        }
        else if (stud[i].finalave > 2.0 && stud[i].finalave <= 2.5)
        {
            stud[i].remarks = 'B';
        }
        else if (stud[i].finalave > 2.75 && stud[i].finalave <= 3.0)
        {
            stud[i].remarks = 'C';
        }
        else if (stud[i].finalave >= 3.00)
        {
            stud[i].remarks = 'F';
        }
    }
     printf("\n");
    printf("Name\t\tAverage\t\tRemarks\t\tScholarship");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    printf("\n%s\t%f\t%c", stud[i].name, stud[i].finalave, stud[i].remarks);
    }
}
```